# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'change_view' with keyword arguments

Tags: django, python-3.x

i am getting error

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'change_view' with keyword arguments '{'view_type': 'sla', 'curr_url': '/home/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['change_view\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']

Using django 2.1.7 and python 3.6 version

i have tried to add both the arguments as dynamic fields in urls.py

home.html

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>View<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li {% if session.view == 'sla' %}class="disabled"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'change_view' view_type='sla' curr_url=request.get_full_path %}"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>SLA</a></li>
    <li {% if session.view == 'priority' %}class="disabled"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'change_view' view_type='priority' curr_url=request.get_full_path %}"><i class="fa fa-trophy fa-fw"></i>Priority</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('change_view/<str:view_type>/', views.change_view , name='change_view'),
]
```

view.py

```py
def change_view(request,view_type=None):
    request.session['view'] = view_type
    request_data = json.loads(request.body)
    curr_url = request_data['curr_url']
    return redirect(curr_url)
```

I want the function change_view to set the request.session['view'] to user selected input and stay on the same url.

Comment: I assume `change_view` url  is already defined in your case. If defined then you just need to use ` path('<str:view_type>/', views.change_view , name='change_view'),
]`

Comment: No its not already defined. if i use ```path('<str:view_type>/', views.change_view , name='change_view'),``` i get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because you are trying to find url with 2 arguments (`view_type` and `curr_url`), but you have only with 1 attribute (`view_type`).
Consider this solution - you will not provide `curr_url` with your request and send user back using `HTTP_REFERER` request header.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>View<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li {% if session.view == 'sla' %}class="disabled"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'change_view' view_type='sla' %}"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>SLA</a></li>
    <li {% if session.view == 'priority' %}class="disabled"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'change_view' view_type='priority' %}"><i class="fa fa-trophy fa-fw"></i>Priority</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

views.py:

```py
def change_view(request,view_type):
    request.session['view'] = view_type
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot spent almost 3 hours debugging this, it works now!!